# Django - ModelChoiceField validation

Tags: django

I have a simple form witch ModelChoiceField. This is a part of my view.py file:

```
def premium(request, id):
    context = {}
    try:
        site = Site.objects.get(id=id)
    except Site.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Nie ma takiej strony")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        premium_form = PremiumForm(request.POST)
        if premium_form.is_valid():
            # group = Group.objects.get(id=request.POST["kod"])
            print('OK')
        else:
            print('NOT OK')
    else:
        premium_form = PremiumForm(site)
        premium_form.fields['group'].queryset = 
premium_form.fields['group'].queryset.exclude(group_name=site.group)

    context['site'] = site
    context['form'] = premium_form
    context['category'] = site.category
    context['subcategory'] = site.subcategory
    return render(request, 'mainapp/premium.html', context)
```

This is my form:

```
class PremiumForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, site, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PremiumForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].initial = 2
        self.fields['group'].empty_label = None

    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Group.objects.filter(is_active=True),
        help_text="<div id='group'></div>",
        label="Some text",
        required=False)
```

My premium.html file:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal'%} <br>
            {% bootstrap_button "Submit" size='large' button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary btn-main-add" %}
        </form>
```

When I press "Submit" button I get "NOT OK". I can't resolve this problem. I don't have any idea how to validate forms.ModelChoiceField. Thanks for any help.

Comment: debug  after POST with print(premium_form.errors) and post  results into the question

Comment: There are no errors with print(premium_form.errors). I get empty line...

Comment: what about non_field_errors?

Comment: Hmm -  I added print(premium_form.non_field_errors) and I got "<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <PremiumForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(group)>>"

Comment: you init the form with site argument but never use it inside. just delete it

Comment: did you solve the issue with that edit?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, then I will post the answer. Please mark it as right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form should be initialised with kwargs:

```
premium_form = PremiumForm(site=site)
```

And inside init:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    site = kwargs['site']
```

However, site is not used inside form initialization so you can just remove it and it will solve the issue.